# Having trouble setting API key for zipline ingestion

Tags: python-3.x, quandl, zipline

I ran the following commands in terminal on a mac running catalina. As far as I can tell my path is correct (I launched cmd from my conda environment)

```
set QUANDL_API_KEY=mykey
zipline ingest -b quandl
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: Please set your QUANDL_API_KEY environment variable and retry`. I believe there may be an error in the set command because when I echo QUANDL_API_KEY nothing pops up. Not really sure what the problem is because I get no error from the set command. Really stuck and have tried everything I know.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue! I think I've solved it by this [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).

The command that worked for me was:

```
conda env config vars set my_var=value
```